# AllowUsers - in SSH does not work

Tags: ssh

I want to allow logins into my Debian server only from 3 IP addresses.

I added the following line on top of the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file:

```
AllowUsers = *@IP_ADDRESS_1, *@IP_ADDRESS_2, *@IP_ADDRESS_3
```

Restarted SSH:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

For some reason it does not work. I still can login from any IP address.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how `AllowUsers` works; from `man sshd_config`: "*This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.  If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.  Only user names are valid*"

Comment: tried this: username1@IP_ADDRESS_1, username1@IP_ADDRESS_2, username1@IP_ADDRESS_3. The same effect - I can login from IP address not listed here.

Comment: Usernames are what you find in `/etc/passwd`.  There are no IP addresses in `/etc/passwd`.  IP addresses are not going to work in the `AllowUsers` line.

Comment: Thanks, Ladadadada; apparently, I couldn't have put it better myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict logins in ssh to certain IP addresses, enable key based logins, disable passwords (optional, but not a bad idea), and in the authorized keys file, you can specify at the beginning of each public key, before the ssh-rsa, the `from=""` directive will let you use hostnames or IPs with wildcards. This will only allow that key, from that host(s).

The other option is to use /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny, in hosts.deny put

`sshd: ALL`

in hosts.allow

`sshd: <the ips you want to allow>`

Comment: Nickw, in hosts.allow should I list all IP addresses in one line or each IP address must start with "sshd:"?

Comment: I've always added them individually, unless they could be grouped under a mask like /29. So a line prefixed with sshd: for each IP address.